# SSIS upstream data source modifiecations

Tags: sql, ssis

I've created an SSIS package that specifies 5 columns of a table that has 10 columns in it as my data source.   This data source is fed to several other SSIS components downstream.

If I then want to change the columns referenced in the data source to either include the other 5 columns or remove columns from the original 5 I had specified, is there a way to easily propagate the additional columns or the lack of to the components downstream?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you've done in your SSIS package. If you have any [asynchronous components](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2008/02/12/ssis-lookup-transformation-is-case-sensitive.aspx), you will need to touch each one of those to let it know the new columns should pass through them.

If your data types are the same and you just want to swap out `column6` for `column4`, you can get that done in your query and it'll just work. Thus

```
SELECT column6 as column4, ... FROM mysource
```

As long as the data types match, SSIS should just roll with it. Future maintainers of your package may not appreciate it though.

Comment: Thanks Bill!  I found an article Jamie Thompson wrote on the subject back in 2005: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/02/11/SSIS_3A00_-Asynchronous-and-synchronous-data-flow-components.aspx  From what he says it sounds like there's probably not an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The new metadata will be propagated downstream automatically. As long as you are not using them downstream, you will not need to modify anything. But if you modify an "original" column from the source, the metadata will need to be refreshed in all the components that use the column. If none of the components use it, you should be fine.

The change cannot be propagated on its own and needs the programmer to go in and check the metadata accordingly on each and every component.

Comment: Thanks rvphx!  It looks like the columns are propagated up until it hits a asynchronous transform, in this case a merge transform and all the transforms under the merge.